# Resource File naming issue with MVC3 - not auto generating code behind

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, embedded-resource

I have an MVC3 application using Razor. I want to localise the application for various languages so I added a App_LocalResources folder and added a resource files as follows:

```
Index_cshtml.en-US.resx

Index_cshtml.en-GB.resx
```

However when I set the code generation on the resource files to public, the code file is created but is empty. If I rename the file to Index_cshtml_en-GB.resx it auto generates the code behind correctly so it looks as if MVC cannot handle the '.en-GB' or '.en-US' in its naming convention. However isn't that the key way an ASP.NET application knows which resource file to use based on the culture set.

I've certainly used this countless times in ASP.NET webform applications, is it different for MVC?

Answer (score 0):

For problems like this an iterative approach might work best. First you might want to try (note the use of . instead of _)

```
Index.cshtml.resx
```

and once that's working then try

```
Index.cshtml.en.resx or Index.cshtml.en-US.resx
```